# Hover image display in middle of page and thumbnail stay

Tags: css

I am trying to do hover image for a gallery. When user mouse over a image, it pop out in the middle of the page with a fixed position but the existing image(thumbnail) still stay in position.

However, not sure what I did wrong the hover image is hoving within the image itself and not the main page.

I had hidden another images for the image that pop out for the main page using  so that the thumbnail in the page will remain in position.But however this image which is in the  is hovering in the thumbnail.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y9w5ym72/7/)

```
 body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      background: #EEE;
      font: 10px/13px 'Lucida Sans',sans-serif;
    }

.wrap {
      overflow: hidden;
      margin: 50px;
    }

/*20 for 5 box , 25 for 4 box*/ 
.box {
      float: left;
      position: relative;
      width: 25%;
      padding-bottom: 25%;
      color: #FFF;


    }
    /*border width control*/
.boxInner {
      position: absolute;
      left: 30px;
      right: 30px;
      top: 30px;
      bottom: 30px;
      overflow: hidden;
      background: #66F;

    }

.boxInner img {
      width: 100%;
    }





.gallerycontainer{
position: relative;
/*Add a height attribute and set to largest image's height to prevent overlaying*/
}





/*This hover is for small image*/
.thumbnail:hover img{
border: 1px solid transparent;
}

/*This hide the image that is in the span*/
.thumbnail span{ 
position: absolute;
padding: 5px;
visibility: hidden;
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
}

/*This is for the hidden images, to resize*/
.thumbnail span img{ /*CSS for enlarged image*/
border-width: 0;
width:200%; /* you can use % */
height: auto;
padding: 2px;
}

/*When mouse over, the hidden image apear*/
.thumbnail:hover span{ 
position:absolute;
visibility: visible;
top: 0;
left: 0; 
z-index: 200;
}
```

Comment: change `position:absolute;` to `position:fixed;` on the .thumbnail hover state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's position is changed to `absolute` not `fixed`, that's why it gets cropped by the parent `span`. If you change it to `fixed` it should work. So, change this,

```
.thumbnail:hover span{ 
position:absolute;
visibility: visible;
top: 0;
left: 0; 
z-index: 200;
}
```

to this

```
.thumbnail:hover span{ 
position:fixed;
visibility: visible;
top: 0;
left: 0; 
z-index: 200;
}
```

you might want to tweak a few other properties such as the `width` though, so it doesn't take `200%` off the page

Here's a [JS Fiddler Example](http://jsfiddle.net/y9w5ym72/8/) where I added the following css declarations

```
.thumbnail:hover span{ 
position:fixed;
visibility: visible;
    max-width:600px;
top: 0;
left: 0; 
z-index: 200;
    left:25%;
    top:25%;
}

.thumbnail:hover span img{ 
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
.thumbnail:hover span{ 
position:absolute;
visibility: visible;
top: 0;
left: 0; 
z-index: 200;
}
```

with

```
.thumbnail:hover span{ 
    position:fixed;
    visibility: visible;
    max-width:600px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 200;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```css
 body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   background: #EEE;
   font: 10px/13px'Lucida Sans', sans-serif;
 }
 .wrap {
   overflow: hidden;
   margin: 50px;
 }
 /*20 for 5 box , 25 for 4 box*/
 .box {
   float: left;
   position: relative;
   width: 25%;
   padding-bottom: 25%;
   color: #FFF;
 }
 /*border width control*/
 .boxInner {
   position: absolute;
   left: 30px;
   right: 30px;
   top: 30px;
   bottom: 30px;
   overflow: hidden;
   background: #66F;
 }
 .boxInner img {
   width: 100%;
 }
 .gallerycontainer {
   position: relative;
   /*Add a height attribute and set to largest image's height to prevent overlaying*/
 }
 /*This hover is for small image*/
 .thumbnail:hover img {
   border: 1px solid transparent;
 }
 /*This hide the image that is in the span*/
 .thumbnail span {
   position: absolute;
   padding: 5px;
   visibility: hidden;
   color: black;
   text-decoration: none;
 }
 /*This is for the hidden images, to resize*/
 .thumbnail span img {
   /*CSS for enlarged image*/
   border-width: 0;
   width: 200%;
   /* you can use % */
   height: auto;
   padding: 2px;
 }
 /*When mouse over, the hidden image apear*/
 .thumbnail:hover span {
   position: fixed;
   visibility: visible;
   z-index: 200;
   zoom: 62%;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
 }
 .thumbnail:hover span img {
   width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link href="overlay2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="" />
</head>


<body>


  <div class="wrap">

    <div class="box">
      <div class="boxInner">
        <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
          <img src="http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-responsive-tiled-layout-with-pure-css/images/demo/7.jpg" /><span><img src="http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-responsive-tiled-layout-with-pure-css/images/demo/7.jpg" /></span>
        </a>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
      <div class="boxInner">
        <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
          <img src="http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-responsive-tiled-layout-with-pure-css/images/demo/6.jpg" /><span><img src="http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-responsive-tiled-layout-with-pure-css/images/demo/6.jpg" /></span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
      <div class="boxInner">
        <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
          <img src="http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-responsive-tiled-layout-with-pure-css/images/demo/1.jpg" /><span><img src="http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-responsive-tiled-layout-with-pure-css/images/demo/1.jpg" /></span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
      <div class="boxInner">
        <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
          <img src="http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-responsive-tiled-layout-with-pure-css/images/demo/2.jpg" /><span><img src="http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-responsive-tiled-layout-with-pure-css/images/demo/2.jpg" /></span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
      <div class="boxInner">
        <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
          <img src="http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-responsive-tiled-layout-with-pure-css/images/demo/3.jpg" /><span><img src="http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-responsive-tiled-layout-with-pure-css/images/demo/3.jpg" /></span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
      <div class="boxInner">
        <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
          <img src="http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-responsive-tiled-layout-with-pure-css/images/demo/4.jpg" /><span><img src="http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-responsive-tiled-layout-with-pure-css/images/demo/4.jpg" /></span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
      <div class="boxInner">
        <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
          <img src="http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-responsive-tiled-layout-with-pure-css/images/demo/8.jpg" /><span><img src="http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-responsive-tiled-layout-with-pure-css/images/demo/8.jpg" /></span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>




  </div>


</body>

</html>
```